# What's the logic of clamp function in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Numeric classes like int, double, num has clamp function. I try it and have some results.. I guess it has a logic like

```
a = math.max(-1, math.min(1, a));
```

but when I print this code I have the strange result

```
print(-100.43.clamp(-400.2, 64.2)); // -64.2
```

What's the algorithm of dart's clamp function?

Comment: try `var a = -100.43; print(a.clamp(-400.2, 64.2));`

Comment: yes.. it works.. I guess function can not get reference? because of this such a bug?

Comment: seems that first `100.43.clamp(-400.2, 64.2)` is executed and then negated with `-` thats why you have `64.2` and then it is negated to `-64.2`

Comment: Simple operator precedence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Clamp function of the dart is actually taking the number not the sign of the number

```
print(-100.43.clamp(-400.2, 64.2)); gives ->  -64.2
```

**because it takes ( -100 ) as ( 100 ) only and if we do =>**

```
100.clamp(-400,64.2) it gives -> 64.2
```

and after negative comes and finally becomes: -64.2
to check this you can do this :

```
print((-100.43 + 0).clamp(-400.2, 64.2))); // it will give: -100.43
```

or

```
double value = -100;
print(value.clamp(-400.2, 64.2)));
```

so you can use this to prevent this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

the implementation is :

```dart
double clamp<T extends num>(T number, T low, T high) =>
    max(low * 1.0, min(number * 1.0, high * 1.0));
```

so what it does, is to return a value between low and high based on the number.
I think the implementation is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Thi behaviour is a result of darts [operators precedence](https://dart.dev/language/operators).

If we refer to the operator table we can see that *unary postfix* (which refers to the `.` between the number and the method `clamp`) operators are higher precedence than *additive* operators.

Knowing this we can derive a fully parenthesized version of the expression you gave.

```dart
// this ...
print(-100.43.clamp(-400.2, 64.2)); // -64.2
// is the same as this
print(-(100.43.clamp(-400.2, 64.2))); // also -64.2
```

A simple way to circumvent this behaviour is to explicitly parenthesize the expression this way :

```dart
print((-100.42).clamp(-400.2, 64.2); // -100.42
```